# WireShark - wireshark trace traffic from my local browser to a local .net application I have with a HttpListener? (e.g. local to local)

Tags: wireshark, packet-sniffer, trace

Can wireshark trace traffic from my local browser to a local .net
application I have with a HttpListener?  (e.g. local to local)

I can't seem to detect this traffic at the moment with wireshark.  Is
there a way to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this artical here: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback.

Given that you're talking about Windows (.NET assumption) then the short answer is that no, wireshark cannot do this out of the box. This is a limitation of the Windows networking stack, rather than Wireshark itself.

On that page there are workarounds, which include installing a special Loopback adapter (and you could then redirect `localhost` to the loopback adapter), or using a commercial sniffer, and then opening the file in Wireshark.